# Razor engine runtime error - Assembly not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have added an assembly Eco.Interfaces.dll V6.0.0.0 to my website but I am getting a compile error at runtime telling me that I need to reference Eco.Interfaces 6.0.0.0

[image: Error page and solution explorer]

The line which causes the error is the first ActionLink

```
Line 36:                 <dl class="SystemMenu">
Line 37:                     <dt>Admin</dt>
Line 38:                     <dd>@Html.ActionLink("Client configuration", "Details", "Configuration")</dd>
Line 39:                     <dd>@Html.ActionLink("Offices", "Index", "Office")</dd>
Line 40:                 </dl>
```

System.Web.Mvc V4 - System.Web.Razor V2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `Copy Local` to `true` for the library using the Properties dialog in Visual Studio.